# getView() method of ArrayAdapter repeats first two items

Tags: android, android-listview, android-arrayadapter, getview

I have 2 types of views in my list.

1. News View
2. Ad view.

getCount() method of the adapter returns the total no of items. But getview always returns the position as 0 or 1. I have used getViewType() and getViewCount() methods.Also i have used Holder. But still, it repeats the items.

here is my code:

```
@Override

    public int getViewTypeCount() {

        return 2;
    }
 @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        if (getItem(position).inMobiNativeAd == null) {
            return NEWS_TYPE;
        } else
            return NATIVE_AD_TYPE;
}
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return super.getCount();
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        int viewType = getItemViewType(position);

        if (viewType == NEWS_TYPE) {
        return getNewsView(position, convertView, parent);
        } else {
            return getNativeAdView(position, convertView, parent);
        }

    }
 private View getNewsView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {


        Holder holder;


        if (convertView == null) {
 convertView = mInflator.inflate(R.layout.news_layout, parent, false);
holder.title=(convertView)findViewById(R.id.title);
-------
------
   convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (Holder) convertView.getTag();
        }
--------
------
   return convertView;
    }

private View getAdView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {


        Holder holder;


        if (convertView == null) {
 convertView = mInflator.inflate(R.layout.ad_layout, parent, false);
holder.title=(convertView)findViewById(R.id.title);
-------
------
   convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (Holder) convertView.getTag();
        }
--------
------
   return convertView;
    }
```

When i use this code, list items are repeated.
But when I use,

```
@Override

    public int getViewTypeCount() {
       return getCount();
}
  @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
return position;
}
```

It works properly. I know this is not the right method. Then why my code is not working when previous method is used. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Um, your method for getNewsView and getAddView are the same, inflating the same layout.

Comment: No. I'm inflating different layout. By mistake I have added the same layout. I'll edit it now

Comment: What are values of your `NEWS_TYPE` and `NATIVE_AD_TYPE`? Note, that they should increase monotonically

Comment: I have given NEWS_TYPE=0 &  NATIVE_AD_TYPE=1.  What do you mean by increase monotonically? Do I need to increment it..But how?

Comment: Your original code for view types should be fine. Can you explain more about what you mean -- do you mean that getView is only called for positions 0 and 1, even though the ArrayAdapter has more than 2 items?

Comment: Actually when I was debugging the code, getView() was returning the positio as either 0 or 1, even the getCount() was returning the total number of items in the list. This is what I'm not getting. When getCount is returning the total no of items present in the list,why getview is returning only 2 positions.